# Ordenar un array de php a partir de un valor específico, explico

Tags: php

Hola estimada comunidad,

Me declaro incompetente para resolver este problema que tengo, he hecho el esfuerzo de probar pero no doy con la solución adecuada. Probablemente alguno de ustedes que son más diestros en el arte de la programación podrán ayudarme.

Tengo un array de 15 posiciones nominadas a partir de 1, cada posicion del array tiene una cadena asociada con rangos o intérvalos horarios; en este ejemplo digamos que son "titulos" de sección para indicar el intervalo horario al cual pertenece, asi, tenemos que:

```
$miArray = ([ 
        1 => '06:15 am - 07:15 am', 
        2 => '07:15 am - 08:15 am', 
        3 => '08:15 am - 09:15 am', 
        4 => '09:15 am - 10:15 am', 
        5 => '10:15 am - 11:15 am', 
        6 => '11:15 am - 12:15 pm', 
        7 => '12:15 am - 01:15 pm', 
        8 => '01:15 pm - 02:15 pm', 
        9 => '02:15 pm - 03:15 pm', 
        10 => '03:15 pm - 04:15 pm', 
        11 => '04:15 pm - 05:15 pm', 
        12 => '05:15 pm - 06:15 pm', 
        13 => '06:15 am - 07:15 am', 
        14 => '07:15 pm - 08:15 pm', 
        15 => 'No definido' ]);
```

Mi plan es mostrar primero el valor correspondiente a "esta hora", suponiendo que en este momento la hora es "08:30 am", el array resultante debe comenzar en la posición 1 con el valor $miArray[3], luego continuar rellenándose desde esta posición hasta $miArray[14], continuar luego con los valores de $miArray[1], $miArray[2] y por último $miArray[15] (que siempre debe quedar al final).

El array resultante debe quedar como:

```
$result = ([ 
        1 => '08:15 am - 09:15 am', 
        2 => '09:15 am - 10:15 am', 
        ... , 
        12 => '07:15 pm - 08:15 pm', 
        13 => '06:15 am - 07:15 am', 
        14 => '07:15 am - 08:15 am', 
        15 => 'No definido' 
])
```

En contexto, tengo un conjunto de datos que debo mostrar por rangos horarios, pero necesito que lo primero que se muestre en esta lista es lo asociado a la "hora actual" como un título, pasado a la vista como una variable generada con un date("H:i") y una pequeña función para calcular en cual posición debería iniciar el array resultante, luego lo de las subsiguientes horas hasta el último rango horario (posicion 13 de $miArray), y luego continue con los rangos horarios que ya "han pasado", y por último los "no definidos".

No sé si mi explicación es suficientemente clara; si es así, por favor indíquenme y hago las correcciones pertinentes.

De antemano gracias y Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Veo errores de escritura (typo) en la variable `$miArray` porque tiene valores repetidos, por lo que no respeta el incremento de la secuencia en el rango de horas, por ejemplo el elemento `7 => '12:15 am - 01:15 pm'` (debería ser `12:15 pm`) y el elemento `13 => '06:15 am - 07:15 am'` (deberían ser `pm` ambos valores)

Haciendo esas correcciones, propondría crear una función a la cual se le envía la hora a procesar `$t` y uno de los rango de hora de `$miArray`. En la función se compara si la hora dada está entre el rango.

```
function check_between($t, $str) {
    $range = explode(' - ', $str);
    if(count($range) == 1) { // No definido
        return True;
    }
    $hc = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $t);
    $h1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $range[0]);
    $h2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $range[1]);
    return ($hc >= $h1 and $hc <= $h2) ? True : False;
}

//  #####
$current = '11:30 pm'; // Valor de prueba
$i = 0;
foreach($miArray as $val) {
    if(check_between($current, $val)) {
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}

$p1 = array_slice($miArray, 0, $i); // Parte inicial
$p2 = array_slice($miArray, $i+1, -1); // Parte final sin el ultimo elemento
$result = array_merge($p2, $p1);
$result[] = end($miArray); // Agregar el ultimo elemento

var_dump($result);
```

Si se pone, una hora que no está en ningún rango, llegará a "No definido" el cual entrará en el primer `if` de la función y se devolverá `True`. En ese momento `$i` debe valer el máximo del índice del array.

Luego con el valor de `$i` se parte el array en 2 y se vuelven a juntar con [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php) empezando por el segundo fragmento, luego el primero y finalmente el último elemento del array original.
Poniendo las `11:30 am` como valor de prueba, la salida es:

```
[
  0=>"11:15 am - 12:15 pm",
  1=>"12:15 pm - 01:15 pm",
  ...,
  13=>"10:15 am - 11:15 am",
  14=>"No definido"
]
```

Como habrás notado, `array_merge()` reindexa el array, por lo que los elementos comenzarán desde **0**, que es como debería ser. Para ponerlo a tu manera, podrías usar un [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-combine.php) y reindexarlo empezando de 1.

Comment: Hola estimado. Si efectivamente el error fue de transcripción. Entiendo el planteamiento que haces. Permíteme por favor analizar la solución que planteas y probar la implementación. Daré respuesta lo antes posible. Te agradezco el esfuerzo.